# No module named 'pycnn'

Tags: pip, dynet

We built a project using [pycnn](https://github.com/clab/cnn-v1). Currently it has been replaced by [dynet](https://github.com/clab/dynet).Now how can we get pycnn back?

Answer (score 0):

Install it from Github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/clab/cnn-v1#egg=pycnn&subdirectory=pycnn
```

Comment: What exactly? Doesn't install? Doesn't import after installation?